# Best way in Docker to add specific ENV variables per user?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Background:   we're making a docker container have all the tools required to develop in(via VSCode remote containers), plus run the CI/CD pipelines.

To remain compliant with the licenses, we need our CI/CD pipelines to use one license server and individuals to use another (pipeline can have unlimited licenses, individuals must come from a shared pool).

Does Docker offer some way of doing ENV per user?  Or should I just append the information to the .bashrc in the created user directories?  Or just have a separate container for the pipeline and the other for the VSCode remote dev container?

Comment: I think a separate container is the easiest way. The shared ENV configurations you can just mount directly into them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Write an image by a Dockerfile which accepts parameteres by `ENV`.
2. Istantiate a different container for each environment passing the specific `ENV` settings.